# \ifmmode check in section caption

Tags: math-mode, macros, sectioning, captions

To assure the correct usage of newcommands which only shall be used in mathmode, I have introduced a `mathcommand`, which checks mathmode by `\ifmmode`.

Now I want to use such a **mathcommand in a section caption**, and the math environment warning appears although the command is used in mathmode:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% provide mathcommand environment
\newcommand{\assuremath}{%
  \relax\ifmmode\else\message{LaTeX Warning: Mathmode command used outside of math mode on input line \the\inputlineno}\fi
}
\newcommand{\newmathcommand}[2]{\newcommand{#1}{#2\assuremath}}
\newcommand{\renewmathcommand}[2]{\renewcommand{#1}{#2\assuremath}}

% define some mathcommand
\newmathcommand{\someMathCommand}{e^x}

\begin{document}
  % use mathcommand in a caption
  \section{I love $\someMathCommand$}
\end{document}
```

I am not familiar with the mechanisms of math mode in section captions. I guess that is the reason why the problem occurs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what happens.

A section title is a moving argument, which means it's stored in memory and written out in the `.aux` file when the next page shipout occurs.

When the write operation is performed, TeX expands macros *without* executing commands; moreover it is *not* in math mode at the time (it is in *no* mode, actually). This means that the conditional is false and `\message{...}` is written to the `.aux` file.

You solve the issue by saying

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\assuremath}{%
  \relax\ifmmode\else\message{LaTeX Warning: Mathmode command used outside of math mode on input line \the\inputlineno}\fi
}
```